# Order reversed when echoing/debugging

Tags: c#, arrays, arduino, uart, serial-communication

I'm trying to send data from a VS Windows Form to an Arduino, but my data keeps getting mirrored. I'm not sure if it has to do with the buffer. If my understanding is correct, it should have nothing to do with the buffer nor to do with my code reading/writing data and it's a timing issue? The buffer is like the queue of the system. Since it's FIFO, the order in which I initialized, it'll have the same order.

I found this article, but I'm not sure if it applies. In [this example about UART Ring Buffer](http://www.simplyembedded.org/tutorials/interrupt-free-ring-buffer/) the head and tail when declared share the same element. Does this apply to regular buffers? I assumed that since it's FIFO the head and tail wouldn't share the same element. 
This [Article on Double buffering](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/uart-double-buffering-technique-interrupt-friendly/) seems to be what I'm talking about, but I don't think I'm technically using 2 buffers?

For example,

```
String a = "1";
String b = "2";
String c = "3";
String d = "4";
String e = "5";
String f = "6";
String g = "7";
String h = "8";
String[] sendchar = new String [] {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
```

So when I send my data, the buffer stream should be, from the right being the first element and left being the last; "h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a" a would be sent first, then b and et cetera.

Currently, when I send data and it gets echoed back, I get in the reverse order, I'll send "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h" but get "h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a" returned.

I'm receiving the data by reading it, and then storing it into an array, duplicating it, and then accessing elements in the duplicated array. This way the data order should be preserved.

```
while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false)
{
    rb = Serial.read();

    if (rb != endMarker)
    {
        receivedChar[ndx] = rb;
        copyarray[ndx] = receivedChar[ndx];
            ndx++;
```

---

How I get the data and send it on Arduino

```
    void loop()
{
    recvWithEndMarkers();//get Data
    Serial.flush();//Clear Input buffer
    delay(10);//delay
    testblink();//Test blink
    //blink();
    echo();//echo data back
    Serial.flush();
    delay(2000);
}
void echo()
{
    for (int b = 0; b <= 7; b++)
    {
        Serial.write(copyarray[b]);// Send b'th element of array
        delay(50);
        Serial.write("\n");//newline character terminates read
    }


void recvWithEndMarkers() {
static boolean recvInProgress = false;
static byte ndx = 0;
char endMarker = '}';
byte rb;
byte comp;

while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false)
{
    rb = Serial.read();//read data from input buffer

    if (rb != endMarker)//not end marker
    {
        receivedChar[ndx] = rb;//store data into array index
        copyarray[ndx] = receivedChar[ndx];//copy data
        ndx++;//next index
        if (ndx >= numBytes)
        {
            ndx = numBytes - 1;
        }
    }
    else//endmarker
    {
        receivedChar[ndx] = '}'; // terminate the string
        recvInProgress = false;
        ndx = 0;//reset ndx
    }


    }
}
```

On the VS side

```
port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++)
        {
            port.Write(sendchar[a]);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        port.DiscardOutBuffer();
        String[] recchar = new String[8];
        while (port.BytesToRead != 0)
        {

            for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++)
            {
                recchar[a] = port.ReadLine();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
        port.DiscardInBuffer();
```

Comment: Am I just lucky it's getting flipped in the reverse order and not jumbled up? Maybe 1 in 8 times the order is weird, but generally it's just backwards

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code on both?  It's kinda hard to see an issue.  Like, how do you send the array of strings "sendChar"? how is "ndx" init? what is "endMarker"

Comment: Also, hard to say, but what I see looks like a simple buffer, not a ring buffer. And UART receive double-buffering is a low-level thing that probably doesn't apply (the Arduino library should handle it -- but I suspect IT uses a ring buffer).

Comment: Sure, I expected what I did was just a simple buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least a couple issues with your code.  First, I assume that you reset the Arduino, then run your windows program, right?

ARDUINO:

- Your recvWithEndMarkers() will probably see Serial.available() == 0, so exit the while loop right away.
- When you put a character in the buffer, you increment the ndx (good).  But when ndx == numBytes, you then set ndx to 7.  It should probably be set to 0.
- Also, you have ndx as a "static".  So it will retain it's value when you run it a second time -- I'll bet that's not what you want.
- When you exit the recvWithEndMarkers() function, you do a serial.flush(), which may cause you to lose characters, esp after the first time.
- Then your echo() routine will "send" whatever is in copyarray[] at the time (not sure on Arduino if it's 0's or 255's, but probably not what you expect).
- If your loop code had the flush and delay at the TOP of the loop (and maybe longer than 2 seconds), you could start Arduino, then start the VS program, and maybe get better results.

On the VS side, I don't see anything quite like that, but you did not share the code that prints the received data.

Good luck!

Comment: 1. Why would it see Serial.available() == 0? The only time this occurs is when there is no data in the buffer? Which is normal?
2. I kind of set this in case the buffer had too much data, so this way the array is never out of bounds, it would just replace the last element. I don't think I need this part.
3. I wasn't aware of that. I thought static would only allow it to be accessed in the function,but I thought that by resetting the ndx to 0 I would avoid it retaining it's value?
4. Is that bad placement? I would have thought it'd be fine since it'll clear the buffer and prevent extra data

Comment: 5. The echo routine is working fine for the most part. It's sending the element stored at the nth address in the array, and on the VS side I just read the element and print it. It works fine, except that address 0 is returning nothing. 6. Does the location of the flush and delay have a significant impact? I assumed after was better since it would use the data and then clear it when finished, compared to using the data, and then clearing it right before using it again? I'll definitely look into that.
The code that prints the received data on the VS is the recchar. I take that array and display

Comment: I guess I should've used numbered bullets.  re: #1 - I would say "normal" is when no data has been received yet. So when it starts, no data has been received, so it would read 0.      #3 "static" --yeah, that's a bad/confusing thing about C.  Outside a function it means "not global", but inside it means, well, static, the opposite of "auto", which is on the static and changes (except here, if you eliminate static, it will be initialized each time).

Comment: Re: #4, #5, #6 -- When I started doing serial, I would take a piece of paper, fold in half, and make notes about what would happen on each side.  You also have to think about what's going to trigger things. For example, I think for you you'll need to start the Arduino first, and the loop should probably check if there are chars available. If not, just return.  If so, then delay long enough for all chars to come in (maybe 1 second), then go into your while loop.  Another totally different approach would be to have loop() see if there's a char, exit if not, save if there is, and send when full.